# appending User Input from a textbox to a new element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a field for users to input text, and add that text to a new paragraph element that is displayed in my current div.

However, I am receiving [object] instead of the user input. Is this because it is not yet a string value? I have been trying to convert my object to a string and I keep returning errors.

```
function addText(){
    var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    var input = document.getElementById('userInput');

    newParagraph.className = 'red';
    newParagraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input));
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(newParagraph);
}

function getText(){         
        addText();
}
```

I am using an input id of "userInput" and triggering the function on the button with `onClick = "getText()"`. The script is working correctly, except returning [object] instead of the userInput text.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="userInput" />
<button id="button" onClick="getText()">Insert Text</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the value of the input, right now you assign the whole input as an object to your `var input`, so it should be:

```
var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your timely response. This site is helping me notice my common mistakes in scripting.